# Express data templates conflict with Vue.js data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

I'm working on an HTML rendering application where my backend framework is in Express and for the front end I'm using Vue.js.

**Backend:**

```
function handleHome(request, response) {
  response.render('home', { title: 'Express' });
}
```

**Frontend home.html and js**

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  <h4>{{ author }}</h4>
  <p>{{ content }}</p>
</div>
```

```
var vm1 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      author: 'Johnnie Walker',
      title: 'Aging Your Own Whisky',
      content: 'A bunch of steps and a whole lot of content'
  }
});
```

When it renders, Express removes all `{{stuff}}` and make it empty and that conflicting with Vue.js. How can I  achieve this without affecting my Express and build the front end manipulation using Vue.js? Basically I want to escape `{{stuff}}` from express. How to do that?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters

Answer (score 1):

Express and Vue.js both use `{{` and `}}` as delimiters for interpolation. You can change these delimiters on the vue.js side with the following:

```
var vm1 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  delimiters: ['${', '}'],  // <--
  data: {
      author: 'Johnnie Walker',
      title: 'Aging Your Own Whisky',
      content: 'A bunch of steps and a whole lot of content'
  }
});
```

Now, you should change your templates to match the given delimiters:

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>${ title }</h1>
  <h4>${ author }</h4>
  <p>${ content }</p>
</div>
```

Above strings will be interpolated by vue.js, instead of Express.

Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters